# Multiple CheckBox in android

Tags: android

I have two checkboxes in my code like for 
qualification (UG and PG checkboxes)

i want that when user choose the checkboxes and click on submit button then in the second activity the text of the checkboxes should appear in the TextView...

I already have created a button and onClick function.... and using intent i am sending data from one activity to another..... but i have no idea of how to send checkbox text to other activity and in other activity how i will show it on textview.....????

Thanks in advance.....

Comment: use getText() to get the text of the Checkbox convert it to String/ add that to intent and in second activity get that value and use setText() to set the text in TextView..

Comment: you can use intent to send values from one activity to another activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When button is pressed do this

```
public void onClick(View v){
String text="";
if(UG.isChecked()){
text="UG";
}else{
text="PG";
}
Intent i=new Intent(firstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
i.putExtra("checkboxValue",text);
startActivity(i);
}
```

in `oncreate()` method of  `SecondActivity` is

```
String value=getIntent().getStringExtra("checkboxValue");
textView.setText(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

In your .java file in 1st activity from which you want your checkbox value:

```
final CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_in_xml);
Button b=(Button) findViewById(R.id.Submitbutton_in_xml);

b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Checkbox.class);

        String str = (String) cb.getText();
        intent.putExtra("variable", str);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
    });
```

your new activity( .java) in which you want to retrieve the checkbox text-value:
Checkbox.class

```
public class Checklist extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_xml_file);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
            String value = extras.getString("variable");

        CheckBox c = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkboxID_in_this_xml);
        c.setText(value);
        }
    }
}
```